# EF Code First and Identity Insert - One Time Identity Insert ON, rest of the time OFF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, guid, identity-insert

I have an application that for the most part has a simple Users table. The PK, UserID, is a Guid. I am using EF Code first, and everything is fine with the following code:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Guid UserID { get; set; }
```

However, at one point in my application, I actually want to force Guids. It's a special case, and outside of this one code block, everywhere else should generate the Guid from the database as expected.

I know in the Seed function in the Initializer I wrote, that I can insert IDs fine. How can I reproduce those conditions so that I can insert an identity value in this edge case?

Comment: I would suggest simply using a stored proc for this one instance.

Comment: Can I write the stored procedure in C# code as opposed to in the DB? I guess probably not. 

I was assuming that the data context passed into the Seed() method has some property manipulated that allows IDENTITY INSERT in this case. I would be fine with some sort of SQL code I had to write in this case in-line.

Answer (score 1):

What if instead of auto generated Identity insert... use a Guid as the primary key and then have a default value of NewGuid().  That way if you don't provide the Guid value one is generated by the database.

No SP required.

**EDIT:**

OR without an autogenerated id, let the entity itself control the initial value.  If you set it's value after construction then it's ok.

With a small change to the entity class in question you can achieve what you want.

```
    class MyEntity {
        public Guid EntityId { get; set; }

        public MyEntity() {
            EntityId = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
    }
```

Comment: EF overrides the default value of the database, so that doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know code first, only db first but it's hard for me to believe that you cannot control the default value of a column.  Either way you can make a small change to the Entity class to achieve the same result.  see my edit.

Comment: This would work. The flaw in it is that any code that updates the Guid that's *outside* the special case would be an error. the Identity Insert on/off sort of provides me mental security that an extra step is needed to alter that column. Not that a rogue developer couldn't misuse Identity Insert...

Comment: @QuintonBernhardt - it's not anything to do with code first.  It's an EF thing.  EF will always insert all fields (unless it's an identity column), which overrides the default value (default value is only used if no field is specified in the insert statement).  Although, it might work if you specify the column as DatabaseGenerated in EF, then use a default value.. but i'm not certain.